# event scheduler in replication master - slave

Tags: mysql, database-administration, percona

I have a problem with Percona MySQL replication (master-slave) and events. When I create any event on master

```
CREATE EVENT `test_event`
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 MINUTE
ON COMPLETION 
PRESERVE
DO
insert into test1 (unix_time) values (NOW() + 0);
```

on master I see for this event `STATUS: ENABLED` and on slave `STATUS: SLAVESIDE_DISABLED` - this is ok, all works correctly. But if I change roles between master and slave: on the new master, this event stays SLAVESIDE_DISABLED and on new slave - ENABLED. Why? Why don't event status change when roles changed? How can I do it automatically?